# how to host ASP.NET Core 7.0 gRPC Server with SSL on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: c#, windows-services, grpc, iis-10

I'm getting conflicting information depending on where I look as to whether IIS 10 can host an ASP.NET Core 7.0 gRPC Server application as it seems to only support TLS 1.2 and possibly a limited version of HTTP

Obviously it works fine in Kestrel on Win10 in VS 2022 with its self signed certificate .. but I'd certainly like to be able to host it in IIS version 10 as I have an unused web site already setup with SSL certificate updates from Let’s Encrypt.

1. Is it possible to host the console app gRPC Server I've created in IIS 10 .. and How?
2. If I must install the Console.exe app as a service, how can I set that up to use the SSL certificate installed for the IIS web site or is there another way to get regularly updated SSL certificates to use with the Service?

And of course any helpful steps to accomplish that would be appreciated!

I've tried searching extensively on Stack Overflow but many of the links say some issues are Solved in .NET 7 and seem to reference a port number without using SSL so I'm unsure what works and what Doesn't work as gRPC Core seems to be a rapidly moving target?

Comment: The certificate and the version of TLS has to be consistent (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).  The certificate contains an encryption mode and some encryption modes only will work in 1.2 and not 1.3.  Some will work in 1.3 and not 1,2.  Others will work in both.

Comment: Let's Encrypt certs need TLS 1.2 or higher so .. I'm fine there.

My question is really whether I have to install my .NET 7 gRPC console app as a Service .. or whether I can get it to run inside IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016?

And if I Do have to run as a Service .. how to use the SSL certificate that's already in place (and auto-updated regularly) on an unused IIS web site (with the domain etc. already working?

Maybe I could just specify the domain name and a port to listen like https://xx.com:5555 as 'xx.com' already has the cert setup?

Comment: This link may help you: [gRPC services with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: There should be no difference running an app a a server than as a regular app as long as the environment is the same (including user).  TLS replaces SSL with better encryption.  TLS the server sends a certificate block with list of certificate names.  Client than looks up in stores the name of the certificate to find matching certificate.  The client can specify a specific certificate name and reject other names.  The certificate has to be loaded in both client and server before it can be used.  The certificate key is never transmitted with the connection, only the name.

Comment: If the gRPC Server app is expected to run in IIS is makes quite a bit of difference where it is run as I found out that only Windows Server 2022 will work (and I'm on Server 2016).

I'm investigating whether Kestrel (which is very different from IIS) will work on Server 2016 and may try to reverse proxy it behind IIS to take advantage of the SSL certificate on IIS.   I've rephrased my question and am using this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829825/can-kestrel-be-used-on-windows-server-2016-to-host-grpc-service

Comment: I found that Kestrel on Windows 2016 Server could run a gRPC server (verified with Postman) but I could Not find a way to access it from the outside.  I tried URL Rewrite and ARR reverse proxy (from IIS) and also having the gRPC Server running in Kestrel listen on an external ip and opening up the port in the firewall but .. I couldn't ever get Kestrel to be visible from the outside.   Next I'll try gRPC JSON Transcoding to get around the HTTP/2 issue (2016 server doesn't seem to support a full HTTP/2) and transcoding uses HTTP/1 which Should work .. hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

gRPC using HTTP/2 is currently Not supported on Windows Server 2016.

I was able to get gRPC working by using HTTP/1 with JSON Transcoding.

The HTTP/2 gRPC is visible to Postman for reflection of the methods on Windows server 2016 but .. it does Not receive a valid response to a message.

This link seems to confirm that Windows Server 2022 is needed for gRPC with HTTP/2

[https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9020)

As I was able to call gRPC with HTTP/2 on Kestrel inside Windows Server 2016 and fully access with Postman - I think there's probably a way to get it working through some kind of reverse proxy and I may try using YARP at a later time:

https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy